# Raspberry Pi 3 + Win IoT Core + Mathematica, is it possible?

Tags: pi-3, windows-iot, wolfram-engine

I am a Windows user so I want to install Win IoT Core on a Raspberry Pi 3. Afterwards, I also want to install Mathematica. Is it possible to install Mathematica on Win IoT Core?

Note: Mathematica that I want to install is Mathematica for Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Windows IoT is not Windows, there is no advantage for the average Windows user (except PowerShell users). Mathematica for Raspberry Pi is a special version for Raspbian. So the answer is NO, it won't run under Windows IoT.

Comment: @LotPings: Oh my ghost. It is a nightmare. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mathematica for Raspberry Pi** is really for Linux OS distros only, like Rasbpian.

[image]

**Windows IoT Core** is simple Windows based ARM kernel that allows you to run single Universal Apps with limited background threads. It is not, as stated before a Windows Desktop environment, it is more like a sandbox. (although more and more features are added constantly)

[image]

<sup>I do not know where to get the other versions from, even though I have a MSDN and Microsoft Parter account - I cannot find these download for testing</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: No, it is not possible to install Mathematica on Windows IoT.